# Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-like

I'm trying to add a like button to all the images uploaded on a page. I got it working, somehow..
When I click `like` on one of the buttons, all the like buttons says `1 likes this`.
It's like they're all connected somehow.

```
http://www.puffys.net
```

That's where I have the problems. I think you will see what I mean.

How can I fix this?

My code looks like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo '
<div align"center" class="images" id="images'.$i.'">
    <a class="image" border="0" href="'.$row['path'].'">
        <img class="img" src="'.$row['path'].'" alt="image" />
    </a>
    <div class="meta" style="padding-bottom:5px;">Lastet opp av <div style="color:#47a09f; display:inline;">'.$row['uploader'].'</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fb-root" style="display:inline;"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d){
            var js, id = \'facebook-jssdk\'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(\'script\'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=144501772249167&xfbml=1";
            d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="0" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div>
</div>
';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to write up some code, but I see you got it working.

To clarify, each 'like' applies to a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). In your case, all the likes were pointing to the same URI.

Comment: Yes, i found out about that and had to change some things. But thanks anyways. :)